# How make complex types on Grahpql

Tags: graphql

i would like to do this on my schema:

```
type Alumno{
  "Retorna algo"
  ID: String
  NOMBRE: String
  NOTAS:  [{
    CURSO: String
    NOTA: String
  }]
}
```

I already know that i can separate NOTAS in other type but is would lke to know if there is a way to do in just one type

Answer (score 0):

No. GraphQL does not support anonymous types.

A field has exactly one type. This type may be a wrapping type, like List or Non-Null, which wraps another type. It may also be an abstract type like a Union or Interface. However, it only has the one type, and that type *must* be one that is explicitly defined inside the schema.